# How to put information in a dynamically generated pdf to tell another program to put an image at a specific page at a specific coordinate?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature, tcpdf

We have a program that generates invoice written in php+tcpdf library. In order to fulfill some compliance factor, the invoice must be sent to a 3rd party API to be stamped with their propertiary QR code image. The invoices generated  varied in the number of pages. By design, the QR code is to be placed at each document's last page.

The original mechanism never actually generate a pdf file and just throw the data to the browser so that the pdf file is only saved after the user saved it to their local drive.

The 3rd party API requires us to send a pdf file and the coordinates of where to put the image.

What we have done so far is create a second server to store the original pdf file, then create a custom application to read the whole file and determine the last page. The info is then used to calculate the correct coordinates. This is sent to the 3rd party API. This solution works but reading whole pdf files creates server load that looks inefficient for scalability.

I have thoughts of slipping the coordinates using custom metadata in the pdf instead, assuming the pdf reader application won't have to read unnecessarily to the end of file.

What I expect for replies are whether our approach are on the right track or not and are there any other solution to do this but not burdening significant server load. The answers don't have to be in a particular programming language.

Thanks

Comment: @KJ thanks for the insight. I will get back to this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know the QR related info when the PDF file is generated. So after the PDF file has been generated, you simply add a comment at the end of the file where you store the QR info. The comments in PDF start with %, so you write something like this:

```
%QR=LastPage:7;X:100;Y:100
```

PDF files end with `%%EOF` so the file will look like this:

```
<pdf data>
startxref
some number here 
%%EOF
%QR=LastPage:7;X:100;Y:100
```

In your custom application you read the last 32 bytes (adjust this to your needs) of the file, search the `%QR=` string and parse the data the follows it.

Comment: I assume this method skips the need for decompressing the pdf file and answers the server load issue?

Comment: @IbnuAlam yes, you do not have to actually parse the content of the PDF file